# Macbook Pro touchbar disabled

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, touch-bar

I have a 13' 2016 Macbook Pro with touchbar and, really frequently, after I wake up the Macbook, the touchbar is completely disabled. I mean, even in the system settings I don't have the touchbar settings. The touchbar is plain black (off) and I have to restart the laptop every-time in order to make it work again.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try using this next time it fails. You may not have to restart your computer every time it fails. https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-kill-and-restart-the-touch-bar-control-strip-on-the-new-macbook-pro-b77e97c11d03

Comment: Already tried that, and did not work. It seams that the Macbook doesn't even recognises that it has touchbar hardware.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a faulty connection to the logic board or a bad touchbar. It should probably be taken in to the Apple store to be checked out.

Comment: I have this problem too. After the computer being on for a couple of weeks, the touchbar dies. It wakes up when I need to authenticate with the touch ID on my MBP 16 so it is working as it should, it is just like it has been turned off. Did ever find a solution?

Comment: And the Medium article is (probably) wrong, I don't have a `Touch bar agent` process, but instead `Touch bar server`.